# Were the Damage Control references in Spider-Man: Homecoming related to the proposed TV show?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming

For some time, there have been rumblings about [a ‘Damage Control’ TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_television_series#Marvel.27s_Damage_Control) set in the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

*Spider-Man: Homecoming* features several references to, and essentially has its plot kicked off by, the [Department of Damage Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Homecoming#Plot), formed by Tony Stark and the U.S. Government in the aftermath of the Battle of New York seen in *The Avengers*.

Has there been any out-of-universe discussion about whether these references were intended to tie-in to the proposed *Damage Control* TV show?

Comment: Related question from sister site: [What is the status of Damage Control TV show after Spider-Man: Homecoming?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76032/what-is-the-status-of-damage-control-tv-show-after-spider-man-homecoming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Homecoming* director Jon Watts mentioned in a Fandango interview that the Department of Damage Control was a thematically appropriate way to kick off the plot of the movie:

> it just fit in with our overall philosophy with the kind of story we wanted to tell. In the same way that Peter gives us the ground-level view of what it’s like to be a 15-year-old kid in a New York City that was almost destroyed by aliens before the Avengers showed up. You also wonder after all those huge messes are made, who’s sent in to clean up? Is it the normal people who would be hired to do something like that? Does it become a government operation? Is it dangerous? What do you do with all the alien body parts that you find? I really like asking those practical questions about this world and then using that to drive the story.
>
> https://www.fandango.com/movie-news/exclusive-interview-spider-man-homecoming-director-jon-watts-on-easter-eggs-iron-man-john-hughes-and-more-752086

Answer (score 0):

Since the TV and movie universes don't always interact, it's likely the TV version would not have lined up with the version they used in the film.  All signs pointed to the pilot being a more "sit-com" tone.

Background for those who don't know the details- Damage Control was a comic miniseries (an eventual total of four) written and created by Dwayne McDuffie (for which he got a posthumous Special Thanks in the film credits). Said organization has made a number of subsequent appearances in the comics, including playing a major role in the company-wide crossover Civil War.

The company has appeared on a couple of the animated series as well.

While she's only named in the credits, Tyne Daly plays Anne Marie Hoag, the founder of the company from the comics in Spider-Man Homecoming.

[Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damage_Control_(comics))